# AutoHotKey IfWinExists Not Working With ReGex

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have a window title something like this:
ComInstr - Q4NATIONAL-11.21(1).pdf - Google Chrome

I want to use IfWinExist to let me know if that windows exists.  I do this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode Regex

IfWinExist i)\..{3,4} - Google Chrome
{   
  Msgbox Here
}
return
```

The title of the window will change, but it will always contain a dot and 3 or 4 characters (an extenstion) and then - Google Chrome.

This doesn't work and I don't know why.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to [escape](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) the comma with `` `, ``.
Otherwise your arguments to the `IfWinExist`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinExist.htm)</sup> command are as follows:

- `WinTitle` = `i)\..{3`
- `WinText` = `4} - Google Chrome`

So, be sure to escape the comma:
`` IfWinExist i)\..{3`,4} - Google Chrome ``

---

But really, you shouldn't use legacy AHK.
`IfWinExist` is a deprecated legacy command and should no longer be used.
Use `WinExist()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm)</sup> along with the modern `if ()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)</sup> instead.

In modern AHK you don't need to worry about the troubles legacy syntax will bring you here since you're explicitly specifying strings inside `""`:
`if (WinExist("i)\..{3,4} - Google Chrome"))`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure why but this works:

```
SetTitleMatchMode Regex 
regex_match:="\..{3,4} - Google Chrome"
IfWinExist %regex_match%
{
```